# Convolution of matrix coefficients is also a matrix coefficients

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, locally-compact-groups

I have a question about the convolution of matrix coefficients as follows:

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group. A Map $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is called a matrix coefficient if there is a finite dimensional, (unitary) representation $(\Phi,V)$ and $v_1,~v_2 \in V$ such that $f(g)=(\Phi v_1, v_2)$ for all $g\in G$.  Let $f,g$ be two matrix coefficients. Then the convolution $f*g$ is also a matrix coefficient.

Is this true? But I have no any counterexample for this. Any hint and comment are appreciated. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm very sorry for the late reply but yes, it is true and it follows from the definition. Indeed, if $f(\cdot) = \left\langle \phi(\cdot)v, w\right\rangle$ is a matrix coefficient of $G$, and $g$ is *any* (continuous) function on $G$, then:

$$(f\ast g)(x)$$

$$=\int_{G} f(xh^{-1})g(h) dh$$

$$=\int_{G} \left\langle \phi(xh^{-1})v,w\right\rangle g(h)dh$$

$$=\int_{G} \left\langle \phi(x)\phi(h^{-1})v,w\right\rangle g(h)dh$$

$$=\int_{G} \left\langle \phi(x) g(h) \phi(h^{-1})v,w\right\rangle dh$$

$$=\left\langle \phi(x)\left(\int_{G} g(h)\phi(h^{-1})dh\right)v,w \right\rangle$$

which is also a matrix coefficient. A similar calculation can be done for the case where $f$ is any continuous function and $g$ is a matrix coefficient. Thus, the matrix coefficients (of a fixed representation) constitute a *two-sided ideal* in the ring of continuous functions (with multiplication given by convolution). Of course, you can also replace *continuous* by *integrable* everywhere in my answer and the result is still true.

Hope this helps!